# Free Directory viewer using PHP / Ajax that can unzip an uploaded file

Tags: php, ajax, directory-structure

I'm not sure if this is the best place to ask this question. However, I accept the possiblity of the question being moved/deleted.

I current have a website that does some file processing if a directory name is provided (local file system). I take the input in an HTML form. I'm looking to incorporate a script that allows the user to upload files / see the directory structure within the website directory. (Instead of them having to remember the name of the folder). However, most importantly, I'm looking for the two following features:

-Ability to be able to click and unzip a .zip or .rar file that they upload (Very important).
-Ability to perhaps incorporate the project as a sidebar using frames (Not that important, I could modify the scripts index page, if I have to).

A really good script, I found online was http://www.filelistpro.com/features.html, however, the problem is that it doesn't handle the option for unzipping a file.

Comment: This might just be it: http://extplorer.sourceforge.net ... However, I'm open to recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ajaxplorer - Demo](http://www.ajaxplorer.info/demo/) - login using demo/demo

More information - http://www.ajaxplorer.info